# BLE Advertising RawData - How to decode?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, ads, iot

I have a E66 Fitness band connected to a gateway and the band does connect to the gateway and I receive data on MQTT. 
But I am unsure on how to decode the RawData format, can someone help me with that?
Thanks

```
{
      "TimeStamp":"2020-05-30 16:44:32",
      "DataFormat":"RawData",
      "BLEMac(hex)":"E5F604C2EAAE",
      "RSSI(dBm)":-30,
      "BLEName":"E67 EAAE",
      "RawData(hex)":"02010610FF107803E8000000000000640023290009094536372045414145"
  }
```

Comment: It seems to be JSON encoded Data.

Comment: I am looking to decode the RawData(hex) parameter value

Comment: Hi @Robin, you found the ble documentation for baceey e66 smart band, if so could not share. I need to get raw heart rate and accelerometer data

Answer (score 13, accepted):

BLE data is decoded as follows:-

- 1st byte = length (n bytes)
- 2nd byte = Types
- n-1 bytes = actual data

And this repeats over the whole raw data. You can find the meaning of raw data [here](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/generic-access-profile/). Going over your example:-

**1st Set**:

- 02: Length: 2 Bytes
- 01: Type: Flags
- 06: Flag - 02 && 04: LE General Discoverable && BR/EDR Not Supported

**2nd Set**:

- 10: Length: 16 bytes
- FF: Type: Manufacture Data
- 107803E80000000000006400232900: Data specific to the manufacturer

**3rd Set**:

- 09: Length: 9 bytes
- 09: Type: Complete Local Name
- 4536372045414145: E67 EAAE (Name of device in ASCII)

I hope this helps.

Comment: How can you distinguish the sets from each other?